# Ms Access SQL: Concatenate seperated by commas one to many relationship

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, query-designer

With the following kind of table:

```
tblRequest
-RequestID(double)
-RequestDescription (String)


tblError
-ErrorID(long integer)
-ErrorName(String)
-RequestID(double)
```

The above relationship is a ONE to MANY relationship.

I want to VIEW the data  in the following manner. Therefore, I need a SELECT query which displays the data in the following manner.

```
Request          Error(s)
1                Error1, Error6
2                Error2, Error3
3.4              Error4, Error2, Error1
```

I tried to search for an answer which involved FOR XML PATH('')). However, I do not think it can work in Ms-Access.

Comment: What relates the two tables? I don't see a foreign key. How do we know that Error1, Error6 are related to RequestID 1?

Comment: I just fixed my question.

Comment: @BaileyS I am not updating my tables. I just want a Select Query to view the data in a manner I specified in my question.

Comment: ^^ This is the correct duplicate target. BTW, using Double for PK/FK is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: The advice about double being a bad key is pretty solid.  Sometimes `1-0.1 = 0.90000000000001`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a potential solution.

**Step 1:**

Create this function in your MS Access App.I don't think this is the most efficient solution, however it should work well enough if the number of records isn't very large.

```
Public Function getErrorText(ByVal MyId As Double) As String
    Dim myrs        As Recordset

    'Create the recordset
    Set myrs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select distinct ErrorID from tblError where RequestID = " & MyId)

    'Build the error string
    Do Until myrs.EOF
        getErrorText = myrs.Fields(0).Value & ", " & getErrorText
        myrs.MoveNext
    Loop

    'Clean up
    myrs.Close
    Set myrs = Nothing

    'Return the correct cleaned up string
    getErrorText = Left(getErrorText, Len(getErrorText) - 2)
End Function
```

**Step 2:**

You should then be able to run the following SQL statement to get the output desired.

```
SELECT distinct tblError.RequestID, getErrorText( tblError.[RequestID]) AS [Error(s)]
FROM tblError INNER JOIN tblRequest ON tblError.RequestID = tblRequest.RequestID
WHERE (((getErrorText( tblError.[RequestID])) Is Not Null));
```